# Click button only once (opensea collection stats api)

Tags: javascript

I'm building a simple app that accesses an API and renders out information. It's activated by an event listener in a button, which takes the value of the html input field and plugs it into my apiCall function. My code then processes the api response and assigns the desired data to a variable inside of an object, which is then console.log'ged out.

Here's my problem: when I click the button the first time, I get this error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'average_price')
    at Object.getAveragePrice (index.js:17)
    at render (index.js:27)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (index.js:33)
```

Then I click the button for the second time, and I get the correct data in my console. What am I doing wrong? Below is my javascript.

```
let jsonResponse = ""
let collectionName = ""
let inputEl = document.getElementById("input-el")
let buttonEl = document.getElementById("button-el")


function callApi(collectionName) {
    fetch(`https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/${collectionName}/stats`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => jsonResponse = response)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
}

const getJsonData = {
    getAveragePrice: function() {
        collectionData.averagePrice = jsonResponse.stats["average_price"]
    }
}

let collectionData = {
    averagePrice: ""
}

function render() {
    callApi(collectionName)
    getJsonData.getAveragePrice()
    console.log(JSON.stringify(collectionData.averagePrice))
}

buttonEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
    collectionName = inputEl.value
    render()
})
```

Comment: it won't hurt to get reference to any element of DOM in DOM Content Loaded event. And you are also calling getJsonData.getAveragePrice() immediately after callApi function. javascript won't wait to get result from function it will call getJsonData.getAveragePrice(). try getting data in callback itself and avoid using global variables instead pass data to functioons

Comment: Can you post the corresponding HTML code?

Comment: <label>Enter Collection Name:</label><br>
   <input type="text" id="input-el" value="doodles-official" placeholder="doodles-official"><br><br>
   
   
   <button title="Click Twice GLITCH" id="button-el" >get average price</button>
   <h1 id="report"></h1>

Comment: I've tried putting it in the dom and I it won't return the response when I do. I need an example maybe.

Comment: @robjus, please include the HTML code within the post, not in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The `fetch` call is asynchronous.  This means that in your `render` function, when `callApi` returns, the request hasn't completed yet.  So the rest of `render` will be working with undefined values until the `fetch` completes - by the time you've clicked the button a second time, the first `fetch` has probably finished, which is why it then works.

At the moment your program flow is

event listener -> `render` -> `callApi` -> (fill in response data)

meaning that the first time, `render` has no response data to work with, but on the second button press, `render` has got the response data from the first run.

So you need to remove `callApi()` from `render()`, and call `callApi()` from the event listener instead of calling `render()`; then, change `callApi()` so that it calls `render()` when the `fetch()` promise is fulfilled.

The program flow will then be

event listener -> `callApi` -> `fetch` -> (fill in response data) -> `render`

Comment: I see what you're saying though I've tried multiple things, and still can't seem to get it to work. here's the update

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70585076/still-getting-a-double-click-error-even-though-the-flow-is-right