# Still getting a double click error even though the flow is right

Tags: javascript

```
let fieldName   = ""
let jsonResponse = ""
let collectionName = ""
let fieldEl     = document.getElementById("field_el")
let inputEl     = document.getElementById("input-el")
let buttonEl    = document.getElementById("button-el")

let collectionData = {
    averagePrice: ""
}
    
const getStatsAvgPrice = {
    currentAP: function() {
        collectionData.averagePrice = jsonResponse.stats["average_price"]
    }
}

function callApi(collectionName,fieldName) {
    fetch(`https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/${collectionName}/${fieldName}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => jsonResponse = response)
    .then(getStatsAvgPrice.currentAP())
    .then(render())
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
}

function render() {
    document.getElementById("report").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(collectionData.averagePrice);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(collectionData.averagePrice))
}

buttonEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
    collectionName  = inputEl.value
    fieldName       = fieldEl.value
    callApi(collectionName,fieldName)
})
```

How can I get this to work? Perhaps make more functions? Add to the dom? Any ideas would be helpful. Still getting a double click error even though the flow is right.

Comment: are you saying that when you click the button and then click it again (before the callApi finishes from the previous click) that you're getting an error?   If not, can you share the error message you're getting?

Comment: `.then` takes a function as an argument, like you have done in (response => response.json()), but you didn't do that with getStatsAvgPrice or render, you are calling those functions and passing the return value to then, which is probably not wanted.  Try removing the parentheses which invoke the function from those two lines `.then(getStatsAvgPrice.currentAP)` and `.then(render)`